# plural form of a person?

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

> The country needs to produce more Elvis Presleys to revive the rock
> music scene.

> The country needs to produce more Elvis Presley to revive the rock
> music scene.

Should you put an s after Presley or not? I am not sure if there's a rule for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely use an "s". "More Elvis Presley" sounds like Elvis Presley is a "mass noun" (like sugar or gasoline) not an individual, countable, person.

Of course the real "Elvis Presley" is unique, so strictly speaking, it isn't pluralizable. You can't really have "more Elvis Presley*s*", but it's easy to understand that you mean "more *musicians* like Elvis Presley."

Comment: As stated above 'Elvis Presleys' is understood within the spoken context, if used in written form it's important to use quotes to emphasize __things or people in the style of__ as shown above.

Comment: Compare "To revive the rock music scene we need more *cowbell*" and "To revive the rock music scene we need more *cowbells.*" (See https://vimeo.com/257364428 if you don't know the reference)

Answer (score -4):

Both of the follow are wrong:

> - The country needs to produce more Elvis Presleys to revive the rock music scene.
> - The country needs to produce more Elvis Presley to revive the rock music scene.

There was only **one** Elvis Presley.

If you put a letter "s" at the end of someone's name, you have just insinuated that the world contains many copies of that person.

> More Elon Musks are required to revolutionize the technology industry.
> More Germanys should join the European Union.
> More Africas are to be discovered in the west.
> More Europes can be found in the South.
> More Donald Trumps would topple the economy.

In some cases, a word refers to a unique thing in the world.

For any strings of text **A**, **B** and **C**, if **B** is the name of a specific person or place, then the following represents an improvement in grammatical correctness:

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| A Bs C | A [plural noun] similar to B C |
| A Bs C | A [plural noun] like B C |

For example, you could write:

> The country needs to produce more **musicians like** Elvis Presley to revive the rock music scene.
>
> ---
>
> The country needs to produce more **cultural icons similar to** Elvis Presley to revive the rock music scene.